# Newlines in AviSynth+ subtitles

Tags: subtitles, avisynth

[This page](https://compactvideo.wordpress.com/2011/03/26/how-to-create-titles-and-captions-using-avisynth/) uses newline characters (`\n`) to introduce newlines in a subtitle in AviSynth:

```
subtitle("First line\nNext line\nLast line", ...)
```

I tried this code on AviSynth+ and it fails.

Newlines would be useful for credits that take multiple lines without having to repeat the settings and tune the alignment.

What is the simplest way to include newlines in subtitles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use newlines in the built-in Subtitle filter, you must specify the `lsp` (linespacing) argument:

```
subtitle("First line\nNext line\nLast line", lsp=12)
```

See [the Subtitle wiki page](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Subtitle) for more info on the argument.

Comment: Yes, I had found the answer at [VideoHelp](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/396069-Newlines-in-AviSynth-subtitles#post2574413) and forgot to update it here.